# Angular js unit testing error

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I have created unit testing for my app, when i run this unit test i got error like this "**Can't find variable: URL**".

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string while creating url.
try using-

```
   var url = new URL('');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your test runner uses a headless browser, maybe, the property window.URL isn't available...

In AngularJS, for having everything testable, don't use global variables...